# Iterate over certain subpaths in Path in Java

Tags: java, nio

I am working with code which makes use of `java.nio.file.Path`. I have a path like

`/tmp/something/first/second/third/last`

which I see only as

`{parent.dir}/first/second/third/{path.end}`

In this example `/tmp/something` or `{parent.dir}` is a path which can be different during runtime and which is irrelevant for me. The same applies for the last element in the path `{path.end}`

What I would need is to iterate over elements between `{parent.dir}` and `{path.end}`. Basically to  test each element in the path if it exists and if it is a file or 
a directory or something else (it doesn't matter).

I am therefore looking for some elegant/simple and proper way to iterate over instance of `Path`where I can access paths like these:

```
/tmp
/tmp/something/
/tmp/something/first
...
/tmp/something/first/second/third/last
```

ideally in this case without the first 2 and the last iteration.

I am looking for a good solution using `Path` and `java.nio` and not the old way. I know I can achieve this  using old `io` API but I am interested in the proper way of using `nio`.

Comment: Where do you get the actual value for `{path.end}` from?

Answer (score 1):

Here I print all directories child of your parent dir:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(${parent.dir})).filter(path -> Files.isDirectory(path, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

You can pass another lambda to the forEach method for your own purpose. 
Also replace ${parent.dir} with your correct value as a String. 
(The code above may throw IOException).

Comment: This is nice, but it iterates over all subdirectories, not just those in the current string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `base` and `end` parts are parameters, while the in-between part is fixed, a solution can look like this:

```
static void iterate(Path base, Path end) {

  if(!base.isAbsolute() || end.isAbsolute()) throw new
      IllegalArgumentException("base must be absolute, end must be relative");

  // test the fixed in-between paths
  Path fixed=Paths.get("first", "second", "third");
  for(Path part: fixed) {
    base=base.resolve(part);
    System.out.print(base);
    if(Files.isDirectory(base)) {
      System.out.println(" is a directory");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println(Files.exists(part)?" is not a directory":" does not exist");
      return;
    }
  }

  // test the end path
  end=base.resolve(end);
  System.out.print(end+(
    Files.isDirectory(end)? " is a directory":
    Files.exists(end)? " is not a directory": " does not exist"));
}
```

It stops the iteration once it encounters a non-directory path component. You will have to adapt this behavior if you want to enforce a specific policy regarding following symbolic links…